# Another "I" vs "me" question

Tags: pronouns, prepositional-phrases

"This ensures she doesn't get paid from any other source besides me."

"This ensures she doesn't get paid from any other source besides I."

Which one is correct? Why? Is there a heuristic you can recommend that I could use in future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Besides* is a preposition, and the object of a preposition is always in the objective case (if that is distinct).

> This ensures that she doesn't get paid from any other source besides me.
>   This ensures that she doesn't get paid from any other source besides him.
>   This ensures that she doesn't get paid from any other source besides her.
>   This ensures that she doesn't get paid from any other source besides us.
>   This ensures that she doesn't get paid from any other source besides them.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, [*besides*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/besides) (sense 5) is a preposition, and in prepositional phrases you use the objective form, so it would be:

> This ensures she doesn't get paid from any other source **besides me**.